# Capturing multicast video

Tags: c++builder, indy10, c++builder-10.3-rio

I have a server that is using VLC to multicast a video using UDP to IP **192.168.139.1** and port **1234** and using RTP with the same IP and port 5004. I can use VLC on the client PC to see the video that is being casted using the address **udp://@192.168.139.1:1234** or **rtp://@192.168.139.1:5004**.

I'm tasked to write an app that can capture this video and save it to a file. To do this I'm trying to use `TIdIPMCastClient` in C++ Builder 10.3.

Here is a snippet of what I have done so far:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Start(TObject* Sender)
{
    FOutFile = new TFileStream(Edit3->Text, fmCreate | fmShareDenyWrite);   
    MCastClient->MulticastGroup = Edit1->Text; // 192.168.139.1 
    MCastClient->DefaultPort = Edit2->Text.ToIntDef(1234); // 1234
    MCastClient->Active = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::MCastClientIPMCastRead(TObject *Sender, const TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    if((nullptr != FOutFile) && (0 < AData.Length))
    {
        FOutFile->Write((void*)&AData, AData.Length);
        StatusBar1->SimpleText = IntToStr(AData.Length);
    }
}
```

but assigning **192.168.139.1** to `MulticastGroup` property of `TIdIPMCastClient` will complain that it is not a valid group address.

So here are my questions:

1. What is the correct way of listening and capturing the UDP data stream?
2. Can `TIdIPMCastClient` also capture the RTP data? If yes, Do I have to do anything special for it? If no, Is the another component that I can use for this?

Comment: The multicast group will be set in VLC and will be in the 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 range.

Comment: `192.168.139.1` is indeed not a valid multicast group IP, so should not be assigned to the `MulticastGroup` property. The group IP where packets are multicasted to, and the local IP that receives the packets, are two different IPs. And no, you can't use `TIdIPMCastClient` to receive the RTP, unless the RTP is multicasted, which is usually not the case. Use `TIdUDP(Client|Server)` instead. Also, you are passing `AData` to `Write()` incorrectly. Use `Write(&AData[0], AData.Length)` instead

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau . Just to be sure, You are suggesting I should use `TIdUDPClient` instead of "TIdIPMCastClient` and set its `Host` property to 192.168.139.1 and `Port` to 1234 and then call the `Connect()` method. Also both the UDP and RTP are being multicasted, but you are saying I would not be able to save the RTP data with Indy?

Comment: @Sam no, that is not what I said. If multicast is truely being used, you have to use `TIdIPMCastClient` with a proper `MulticastGroup` (in the 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255 range) *otherwise* use `TIdUDP(Client|Server)` instead (either one will work, I would opt for Server myself) but 192.168.139.1 is the receiving IP, not the sending IP, so you don't `Connect` to it at all, you bind to it for listening instead (`TIdUDPClient.BoundIP` or `TIdUDPServer.Bindings`). You can certainly save RTP, but you are just not saving it *correctly* (if you can receive it at all).